# SwiftUI NSCache cache object

Tags: ios, swiftui, nscache

Hi everyone there is a method simil NSCache used in Swift with Class for SwiftUI? Ive try NSCache but not work with Structure.
thanks

Comment: here is a good article about making a wrapper for NSCache: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/caching-in-swift/